# How to integrate in laravel filament form the model connected through hasOneThrough relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-filament

I have ClientResource and wants to add in the form the fields from the model Status. The structure of model draws like this:
Client -> Category -> Status

I can add Category fields through relationship() function. But when I include Status fields, it wont include since the model is connected through hasOneThrough relationship. Please help

I tried relationship() but it doesnt work